# Is Varna and Bodily Gunas have a similar system to genetics

Tags: caste-system, dharma-shastras, varna, varnashrama, caste

Varna is based on birth or one's Gotra, but I found some similarities when studying simple Mendelian genetics keep in mind this is simple and not modern genetics. Now I am not saying necessarily that genetics and Varna are related, but is there a similar pattern of dominance and recessiveness there?

Below is a basic paragraph of different results in simple Mendelian genetics:

"A high born and a low born, form pure breeds of their respective status when their birth is amongst themselves. Else a high born and a low born together form mixed borns. Two mixed borns form two mixed, one high and one low. A mixed born and a high born, form a high born half as much as a mixed born. While same with a mixed and a low except half the chances is with the low born instead of high."

Keep in mind born refers to which allele is being expressed or trait for example, purple is dominant or high (P), while white is recessive or low (p) as colors in flowers. A pure breed is either PP or pp while a mixed person is Pp which is the dominant trait being represented. These sound similar to how a paternal gotra is dominant to a maternal gotra. Again I am not equating genetics with Varna or stating that Varna is scientifically provable I am stating if the system in decision is similar in certain aspects.